# Creating and graphing Hierarchical Trees in Python with pandas

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas, tree, hierarchical-clustering

So I have hierarchical information stored within a pandas DataFrame and I would like to construct and visualize a hierarchical tree based on this information.

For example, a row in my DataFrame has the column headings —
['Phylum','Class','Order','Family','Genus','Species','Subspecies']

and I want to create a tree with each row, where all 'Subspecies' are unique strings and should be leaves in the tree. Can someone point me to the best method/package etc... for doing this? ideally the output will be a matplotlib object. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3):

You can easily get them in a hierachical index with groupby:

```
taxons = ['Phylum','Class','Order','Family','Genus','Species','Subspecies']
hierarchical_df = my_dataframe.groupby(taxons).sum() #sum or whatever is most appropiate for your data
```

From there, I'm also trying to do a meaningful plot showing that hierachy
(see [Hierarchic pie/donut chart from Pandas DataFrame using bokeh or matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33019879/hierarchic-pie-donut-chart-from-pandas-dataframe-using-bokeh-or-matplotlib))